# Ext js summaryRenderer function not calling

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs3, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

```
This is my view
Ext.define('view.OrdersGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.ordersgrid',
    store: 'TicketOrders',
    features:[
        {
            ftype: 'groupingsummary',
            groupHeaderTpl: [
            '{[values.rows[0].data.EventName]}&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;<small class="muted">{[values.rows[0].data.EventDate]}</small>',
            ],
            //hideGroupedHeader: true,
            //collapsible: false,
            remoteRoot: 'record',
            //showSummaryRow: true,
        }
    ],

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.on('edit', function (editor, e) {
            me.getSelectionModel().select(e.record);
            me.fireEvent('onEdit', e.record);
        });
        me.selModel.on('select', function (t, record, index, eOpts) {

            me.fireEvent('onRecordSelected', record);
        });
        me.selModel.on('deselect', function (t, record, index, eOpts) {
            me.fireEvent('onRecordSelected', record);
        });

        me.columns =
        [
        {
            id: 'order',
            text: "Order Id",
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'TOId',
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            text: "Order Number",
            flex: 1.5,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'OrderNumber',
            renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                if (record.get('OrderStatus') == 3) { // error orders

                    return value + "  <img src='images/icons/icon_question_mark.gif' title='" + record.get('Description') +  "'/>";
                }
                else {
                    return value;
                }

            }

        },
        {
            text: "Event",
            flex: 3,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'EventName',
            hidden: true,
            //summaryType: 'sum',
            renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                return value + "  ( " + record.get('TicketCount') + " )";
            }

        },
        {
            text: "Price",
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'TotalCharges',
            //summaryType: 'sum',
            //renderer: function (value, summaryData, dataIndex) {
            //    debugger;
            //    return parseInt(value);
           // }
            summaryRenderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                debugger;
                return Ext.String.format(
                         "Total: {0}",
                         Ext.Number.toFixed(value)
                 );

            }

       }
      ];

        this.callParent(arguments);

    }, // end init function


    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        })
    ], //end plugins
}
);

This is my model

Ext.define('model.TicketOrder', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
    'TOId',
    'OrderNumber',
    'EventName',
    'TicketCount',
      {
          name: 'TotalCharges',
          type: 'int'

      }

    ],
    idProperty: 'TOId',

    proxy: {
        // load using script tags for cross domain, if the data in on the same domain as
        // this page, an HttpProxy would be better
        type: 'ajax',
        disableCaching: true,
        url: 'WebService.asmx/GetTicketOrdersByUserId?userId=' + Utilities.UserId,
    reader: {
            root: 'orders',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        },
        // sends single sort as multi parameter
        simpleSortMode: true
    }
});

This is my store
Ext.define('store.TicketOrders', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'model.TicketOrder',
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteSort: false,
    pageSize: 50,
    groupField: 'EventOriginalId'


});
```

I am using MVC architecture, I have put a debugger in summaryRenderer in view but it is not executing and not showing any summary row, need help please. Also tell me what the remoteRoot should be set..`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Un-comment out 'showSummaryRow: true" you will need this. Then for each column you define that you want a summary on you will need to define the `summaryRenderer: function() {...}` and `SummaryType: 'sum'`. EXTJS can be a real pain, especially when you want to do something custom. Watch out for extra commas (looks like you've got a couple in the features portion). Try to keep it as simple as possible. Best of luck!

```
features:[
    {
        ftype: 'groupingsummary',
        groupHeaderTpl: [
        '{[values.rows[0].data.EventName]}&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;<small class="muted">{[values.rows[0].data.EventDate]}</small>',
        ],
        //hideGroupedHeader: true,
        //collapsible: false,
        remoteRoot: 'record',
        showSummaryRow: true
    }
],
```